# как сохранить данные моего модуля в структуре nf_conn?

Tags: linux, iptables, ядро

Хочу создать модуль ядра, для расширения функциональности conntrack, изменять код самого ядра не хочу. Мне необходимо в структуре nf_conn https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.h#L75 , либо в структурах связанных с ней, сохранить пару указателей на свои данные и затем использовать их.
Нашёл для старой версии ядра сомнительную реализацию https://www.programmersought.com/article/25201368754/

Можно ли это сделать без вмешательства в код ядра?